# Build library in target for cross compile in Host

Tags: linux, qt

Usually a cross compiling a package(library) means building the package in host using a toolchain of host for target machine.

**Yet, there seems to be another alternative**:

Build package in target (using the native gcc), and then copy the .so from /usr/lib and the relevant header files from /usr/include files into Host sysroot, so that we can cross compile in host (instead of doing the cross compile of a package in host and copy to target) .

I consider using this method with to large packages like qt5 and gstreamer.

**Should this method always work, even with such big packages like qt ?**

Answer (score 1):

How fast is your target? How much RAM and disk space do you have?

If your target is a full embedded PC with a quad core i7, 16G RAM and 500G SSD, then you should have no problem (I've worked with these "embedded" PCs for image processing).

If it is a low end ARM Processor with 2 cores, 4G RAM, and 32G SD Card, you are not going to be happy trying to build Qt on it, if it is even possible.

Comment: The target is low in resources.This is why I need cross compile and debug in the first place. But my question is not about that. I was actually asking if the method of building it all in target and then copying to host should always work.

Comment: How well building on the target and copying to the host works really depends on how well your tools are setup. For all of the projects I have done, it has worked very well because we took the time to make sure everything we needed was on the target already or copied.

Comment: Oh yes, another idea is to remote mount the target file system from the host. Then you don't have to deal with the copy step.  It is already available on the target. (I've done this too.)

Comment: Thanks, I think you can put it in a separate answer, but that's the answer I was looking for :) Thx